# Static local IP/gateway config on startup issues

Tags: raspbian, networking

I'm using a BT Homehub 3 and trying to set up my PI using raspbian with a static local IP.

Before any changes, using dhcp, the output of `$ netstat -nr` is

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

The dhcp normally starts at `192.168.1.64` but I've changed this to `192.168.1.66`.  My windows server uses `192.168.1.64` and I want the Pi to use `192.168.1.65`.  The following shows changes I've made (commented out line 5,6 added line 8-14) to config in `/etc/networking/interfaces`:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.65
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.254
broadcast 192.168.100.255
gateway 192.168.100.254

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

The config changes result in the local IP for the Pi changing but the output of `$ netstat -nr` is now the below and whilst I can access the Pi from the network on `192.168.1.65`, I cannot access the internet from the Pi.  I can see the problem, no gateway but as this is configured in the interfaces file above I'm stuck as to how to fix it.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

`$ sudo /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.254 eth0` at this point adds the requisite gateway and all works as required but I want this to be done automatically on startup.

Any help?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration has the broadcast and gateway on a different network I think you meant this:

```
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

(instead of 192.168.**100**.x)

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the following command on the shell, you are giving a Gateway IP Address that falls in the range of your Subnet Mask (255.255.255.0)

$ sudo /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.254 eth0

But in your /etc/networking/interfaces file, the gateway that you are giving is 192.168.100.254, which is not in the range of the subnet mask, hence possibly the problem.

I personally dont give the Gateway Address in the interfaces file, and it still works for me, when I use Static IP. (I never connect it to the internet though).